# In what situation "you will have shown" can't be substituted with "you will show"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, future-perfect

My point is whether there is such a context, in which "you will show" would really change the meaning if it is substituted for "you will have shown".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sentences:

> After we've seen your performance, *you will have shown* us your talent.
>
> After we've seen your performance, *you will show* us your talent.

the first sentence implies that the "showing of talent" takes place as part of the performance. The second implies that it will happen after the performance. So the meanings are different.

Answer (score 0):

"You will have shown" is a phrase using the future perfect, which is normally used when describing an event in the future to show its relevance with another event in the future, or when describing an action that will take place before some specified or predictable time. The time could also be specified by a previous sentence, or clause.

> By then, you will have shown what you meant to do since the beginning.

Comment: If I say "By then, you will _show_ what you meant to do since the beginning", will it change the meaning?

Comment: Probably not, but I don't think it is something a native speaker would say. The simple future is incompatible with the "by then".

Comment: @Colin Fine: When I google "by then you will" it gives me a lot of cases when "by then" is used with Future Simple (true, the majority of cases are Future Perfect). Most such cases come with the verb "be", for example, "by then you will be able to" or "by then you will be in love with her already", perhaps, because they are expressing a state of being rather than a by-then completed action. Cases with "by then" + Future Simple become predominant when the verb is in negation - when I google "by then you will not", I almost always get Future Simple.

Comment: True, with a stative verb, or a continuous form, "by then you will ..." is fine. I was thinking of dynamic verbs.